# Rust - Associated type with generics

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement `serde::Deserialize` on an external type (which uses type params) using the newtype pattern. In the process I need to implement the visitor trait which has an associated type.

However I am getting `unconstrained type parameter` errors and I am unsure how to fix these in this case:

```rust
pub struct Money<'a, T: rusty_money::FormattableCurrency>(rusty_money::Money<'a, T>);
struct MoneyVisitor;

impl<'de, 'a, T> Visitor<'de> for MoneyVisitor { // unconstrained type parameter for 'a and T
    type Value = Money<'a, T>;

    //...
}
```

If I add type params to `MoneyVisitor` too I get errors about them being unused since it is an empty struct.

Comment: Stable Rust does not yet support generics in associated types, but it's just landed in nightly Rust recently, so it will be possible soon: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265 Also, you should be able to derive Serde traits for remote types automatically: https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html. Lastly, it may help people give you a solution if you link to a full reproducible code example.

Comment: @Jimmy GATs won't be the answer here since all serde types have been designed without it. I'm guessing `MoneyVisitor` should be generic over `'a` and `T`, though I agree that seeing a full example would clear that up.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, you're right. The only reason I mentioned GATs is to explain the compiler error message. The "unconstrained type parameter" error is because, even though `'a` and `T` are being used in the definition, they're being used in the associated type (as opposed to the self type or the trait), which Stable Rust does not yet support. You are right that GAT support is not necessary to solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to:

- add generics to `MoneyVisitor`
- use `PhantomData` to prevent the compiler error about unused generics

```rust
struct MoneyVisitor<'a, T>(std::marker::PhantomData<&'a T>);
```

`PhantomData` is a special type which is allowed to have generic parameters that it doesn't use. So if you want a struct to "encode" some types, even if it has no actual fields of that type, you'll need to use it.

Then when you come to implement the trait, you can use those generics in the definition to avoid the "unconstrained type parameter" errors

```rust
impl<'de, 'a, T> Visitor<'de> for MoneyVisitor<'a, T> {  parameter for 'a and T
    type Value = Money<'a, T>;

    // ...
}
```

Here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=639822d98d985df196c7e2f674333891) which has this code.